# rust: How to consume a `dyn` argument in a `new()`

Tags: rust

Rust noob here, but otherwise experienced programmer.

I have a parser struct. You hand it a stream of bytes as input, passing ownership so that afterwards you can't use the input stream anymore, because the parser is using it.

This compiles, but it just feels a bit smelly. I'd love some feedback if there's a more idiomatic way to do this.

```rust
pub struct Parser {
    /// The source of raw bytes
    // I have to use dyn instead of generic'ing
    // this struct for other reasons.
    reader: Option<Box<dyn Read>>,
    // other stuff
}

impl Parser {
    pub fn from_reader(reader: Box<dyn Read>>) -> Self {
        Self {reader}
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let file = File::open("path").expect("Couldn't open file");
    // This just feels weird that I need to Box the file here.
    // I would think I should just be able to pass &file somehow,
    // that just seems cleaner?
    let p = Parser::from_reader(Box::new(file))
}
```

Comment: _"This compiles..."_  But... it doesn't. The code in your question doesn't compile for four separate reasons: extra `>` in `Box<dyn Read>>`, you can't do `Self {reader}` if the type of `reader` doesn't _exactly_ match (one is `Box` and the other is `Option`), you are missing a `;` at the end of `main()`, and `Read`/`File` aren't imported.

Comment: I apologize, you're entirely right. I appreciate that people helped even though I didn't do my due diligence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you state that you want to pass ownership « so that afterwards you can't use the input stream anymore, because the parser is using it ».
But in your code you write that you would prefer « just be able to pass &file somehow ».
Those two requests are incompatible, because `&` or `&mut` do not transfer ownership, they just borrow the value which is still available and usable after the function call.

Please find below three variations around your code.

The first (`DynParser`) is just yours, with minor changes to make it compile and run.
It transfers ownership and uses dynamic polymorphism.

The second (`GenParser`) is the generic equivalent.
It transfers ownership and uses static polymorphism; no `Box` is needed.

The third (`RefParser`) is the borrowing equivalent.
It does **not** transfer ownership, but still uses dynamic polymorphism thanks to the `dyn` reference it holds.

```rust
use std::{fs::File, io::Read, slice};

pub struct DynParser {
    reader: Option<Box<dyn Read>>,
}
impl DynParser {
    pub fn from_reader(reader: Box<dyn Read>) -> Self {
        Self {
            reader: Some(reader),
        }
    }
    pub fn parse(&mut self) -> Option<u8> {
        if let Some(reader) = &mut self.reader {
            let mut b = 0;
            if let Ok(n) = reader.read(slice::from_mut(&mut b)) {
                if n > 0 {
                    return Some(b);
                }
            }
        }
        None
    }
}

pub struct GenParser<T: Read> {
    reader: Option<T>,
}
impl<T: Read> GenParser<T> {
    pub fn from_reader(reader: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            reader: Some(reader),
        }
    }
    pub fn parse(&mut self) -> Option<u8> {
        if let Some(reader) = &mut self.reader {
            let mut b = 0;
            if let Ok(n) = reader.read(slice::from_mut(&mut b)) {
                if n > 0 {
                    return Some(b);
                }
            }
        }
        None
    }
}

pub struct RefParser<'a> {
    reader: Option<&'a mut dyn Read>,
}
impl<'a> RefParser<'a> {
    pub fn from_reader(reader: &'a mut dyn Read) -> Self {
        Self {
            reader: Some(reader),
        }
    }
    pub fn parse(&mut self) -> Option<u8> {
        if let Some(reader) = &mut self.reader {
            let mut b = 0;
            if let Ok(n) = reader.read(slice::from_mut(&mut b)) {
                if n > 0 {
                    return Some(b);
                }
            }
        }
        None
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    std::fs::write("path", "a bb ccc\n").unwrap();
    {
        let file = File::open("path").expect("Couldn't open file");
        let mut p = DynParser::from_reader(Box::new(file));
        while let Some(b) = p.parse() {
            println!("byte {:?}", b)
        }
    }
    println!("~~~~~~~~");
    {
        let file = File::open("path").expect("Couldn't open file");
        let mut p = GenParser::from_reader(file);
        while let Some(b) = p.parse() {
            println!("byte {:?}", b)
        }
    }
    println!("~~~~~~~~");
    {
        let mut file = File::open("path").expect("Couldn't open file");
        let mut p = RefParser::from_reader(&mut file);
        while let Some(b) = p.parse() {
            println!("byte {:?}", b)
        }
        // file is still available and usable here
        println!("file: {:?}", file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is an excellent answer. I really appreciate the comparisons and alternatives, it really helps with translating between the solutions when I started with one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect that you do not know the actual type of the data passed to you, then your approach is probably correct. If, however, you think that the type is known when `new` is called, and you just want to erase it afterwards, then you can make it generic instead:

```rust
impl Parser {
    pub fn from_reader(reader: impl Read) -> Self {
        Self { reader: Box::new(reader) }
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let file = File::open("path").expect("Couldn't open file");
    // This just feels weird that I need to Box the file here.
    // I would think I should just be able to pass &file somehow,
    // that just seems cleaner?
    let p = Parser::from_reader(file)
}
```

Besides, nothing prevents you having both constructs available, so that the consumer of your struct can choose.